# <a> href how to know baseurl in angular html template

Tags: html, angular, href

In an angular html template how do I get the base url, in order to redirect the user to theproper page of the site?

example:

```
<a href="mybaseurl/SearchBooks">search books</a>
```

Comment: You don't use an absolute URL, you use the Angular router.

Comment: how do I do that, any example?

Comment: have you setup base href - watch this video tutorial once if possible : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Std1QJpMEiE will probably help resolve your issue.

Comment: Better than that, [the whole documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router).

Answer (score 1):

[Angular Router](https://angular.io/guide/router) is used for navigation from one view to the next.